# Android: Files are only being stored in internal storage and not SD card

Tags: android

I want to save pictures to the SD card as it has plenty of space; however, despite my efforts, the pictures appear to still be saving under internal storage.

CameraFragment.kt:

```
var outputDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)!!
outputDirectory.mkdirs()
```

Is that the correct way to do it?  I have also requested permissions in the app:

PermissionsFragment.kt

```
Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Have a look at the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: getExternalFilesDirs() in my SDK returns a File not a File[].  Am I looking in the wrong place?  Ah, it is getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: You mean the internal SD card or the one you can take it out from your device?